# Android: How to execute some code only when I update the app on market?

Tags: android, versioning, google-play

I need to know if there's a way to run a piece of code in my app only first time when  the user installs my new updates from market(google play) ?

I need to run the code once each time I upload a new version of my app ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: it is possible though "how" depends on your exact needs... please elaborate... how "foolproof/hackerproof..." should that be ? is it ok if the same user execute the code twice because they restored their phone from backup (with old version) and installed the update a second time for example ?

Comment: Only if I update the application with new version @Yahia

Comment: Sorry but that is not an answer to the questions I asked and thus still unclear!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use SharedPreferences to store the last version and the current version of your app, and run the code once on every version change. Something like:

```
    public static final String LAST_VERSION = "LAST_VERSION";
    public static final int VERSION_CODE = 4; // Same as the version code in your manifest.

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

    mContext = this;

    int last = prefs.getInt(LAST_VERSION, 0);
    if (last < VERSION_CODE) {
        //Your code
        editor.putInt(LAST_VERSION, VERSION_CODE);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: I think this is dangerous. BEcause if the user reset the phone or clear the cach then shared pref are cleared. And as a result you will be executing the same code

Comment: Mostly code executed once per update is used to pre populate shared preferences and stuff like that, which will need to be re populated when the phone or app is reset anyways.

Comment: this answer is wrong, instead you should use BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE since is a cleaner approach than using a constant that you have to update manually to match exactly BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE